# Using an if statement inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to make a batch file to solve the first Project Euler problem, http://projecteuler.net/problem=1, but I need an if statement inside my loop to check if n modulo 3 or 5 is 0. And the sum has suddenly stopped working.

My code:

```
echo off

set sum=0
for /l %%n in (1,1,999) do (
    set a/ sum+=%%n *(only add if n%%3 == 0 or n%%5 == 0)*
)

echo %sum%
pause
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very efficient solution, though it is a bit obfuscated:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a sum=0
for /l %%N in (1 1 999) do set /a "sum+=%%N/!((%%N%%5)*(%%N%%3))" 2>nul
echo %sum%
```

The expression `(%%N%%5)*(%%N%%3)` yields zero if `%%N` is divisible by 3 or 5, or non-zero if it is not divisible by either. The `!` takes the inverse logical value, so 0 becomes 1, and non-zero becomes 0. Dividing `%%N` by that expression yields either `%%N` or a division by zero error. So simply add that entire expression to the sum, and redirect error messages to nul.

Final result - only numbers divisible by 3 or 5 are added :-)

Answer (score 0):

> And the sum has suddenly stopped working.

I think your sum stopped working because your `set` needs to have the slash in front of the 'a', and not behind it, like this:

```
SET /A sum+=%%n
```

Also, there isn't an OR operator in DOS Batch, so you'll need to use a nested IF for that.  This worked for me:

```
echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set sum=0
for /l %%n in (1,1,999) do (

    SET /A mod3=%%n%%3
    SET /A mod5=%%n%%5

    IF !mod3!==0 (
        SET /A sum+=%%n
    ) ELSE (
        IF !mod5!==0 (
            SET /A sum+=%%n
        )
    )
)
echo %sum%
ENDLOCAL
```

If you need more help, check out Rob van der Woude's Scripting pages.  Specifically, here is a link to his page on performing [mathematical operations in DOS batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php).

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set /A sum=0
for /l %%n in (1,1,999) do (
 CALL :modulo %%n
 IF DEFINED addme set /a sum+=%%n
REM CALL echo %%n %%sum%% %%addme%%
)

echo %sum%

GOTO :EOF

:modulo
:: set addme if %1 %% 3 == 0 or %1 %% 5 == 0
SET /a addme = %1 %% 3
IF %addme%==0 GOTO :EOF 
SET /a addme = %1 %% 5
IF %addme%==0 GOTO :EOF
SET "addme="
GOTO :eof
```

Simply pass each value to the `:modulo` routine in turn and set a flag value to (clear or not)

OR

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set /A sum=0
for /l %%n in (1,1,999) do (
 SET /a mod=%%n %% 3
 IF NOT !mod!==0 SET /a mod=%%n %% 5
 IF !mod!== 0 set /a sum+=%%n
rem CALL echo %%n %%sum%%
)

echo %sum%

GOTO :EOF
```

which does the same thing using delayedexpansion.